# How to insert into another table if one of two columns has been updated in Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to insert values into another table with an after update trigger in the SQL server.

I have a table where I am storing my employees (employee_id, name, exam_results, exam_date) and I need to make a trigger that allows me to insert employee_id, exam_results, and exam_date into a table called exams_backlog whenever exam_results or exam_date is updated in table employees.

I don't know if I am able to check those fields to make the insert.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateExamBacklogTrigger 
   ON  employees
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    *****HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CHECK IF ONE OF THOSE TWO FIELDS HAS BEEN UPDATED*****

        INSERT INTO exams_backlog SELECT e.employee_id, e.exam_results, e.exam_date FROM employees e

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

END
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have just edited the question to show what I have so far! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `INSERT` the columns like `employee_id` have no context. You can't reference a column without a `FROM`. Presumably you should be referencing the `inserted` pseudo table.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15?

Comment: @Larnu You are right, I have edited it to make an insert into with a select. Thanks!

Comment: Do you *really* want to do to process for *every* row in the table `employees` when only a few of the rows are updated?

Comment: @Larnu No I don't, that's the point, I don't know how to only insert into the backlog table  those rows that have been updated, anyway I think that I'm almost there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I've been looking for:

As I wanted to check if exam_results or exam_date had been updated I have used

```
IF(UPDATE(exam_results) OR UPDATE(exam_date ))
```

And then in order to only insert data for those employees that had been updated I used an

`INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.employee_id = e.employee_id`

So the complete trigger results as this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateExamBacklogTrigger 
   ON  employees
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

IF(UPDATE(exam_results) OR UPDATE(exam_date ))

    INSERT INTO exams_backlog SELECT e.employee_id, e.exam_results, e.exam_date FROM employees e INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.employee_id = e.employee_id

SET NOCOUNT ON;

END
GO
```

Comment: Nope - IF UPDATE does not do what you think. If you only want to do this when the actual value changes, then you MUST compare the "old" version and the "new" version. In addition, there is no need to join inserted to employees - the insert table has all of the current information for the updated rows. Lastly stop the lazy coding - always specify the column list in an INSERT statement.